# Node js grabbing failure

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently started learning node js and using online tutorials.

I am trying to grab the user name and a little greeting but it keeps failing to get it. There is a if statement to check if it fails, if it does it will output "you blew it". Here is the code:

```
function grab(flag){
    var index = process.argv.indexOf(flag);
    return (index==-1) ? null : process.argv[index+1]
}

var greeting = grab('--greeding');
var user = grab('--user');

if (!user || !greeting){
    console.log("you belew it")
}else {
    console.log('welcome ${user}, ${greeting}');
}
```

This is the way I am passing data

```
node app.js --user Stack --greeting "hello"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
grab('--greeding');
```

to

```
grab('--greeting');
```

Be careful

Comment: thanks! I didnt even notice that. Im using sublime editor and it didnt really pick this up.

Comment: @SA sublime is just a text editor - don't expect it to find your mistakes. Use an IDE if you want behavior like that